# How to add another private cocoapod library to the private cocoapod library?

Tags: swift, dependencies, cocoapods

I created two private cocoapod libraries, A and B, using the 'pod lib create' command.

I wrote A Podfile and A.podspec of A to use B pod in A pod as below. (Of course, B pod was uploaded using 'pod repo push' command. I also created a Single App to test whether the B pod is available.)

This is A Library's Podfile.

```html
use_frameworks!

target 'A_Example' do
  pod 'A', :path => '../'
  pod 'B', :git => 'https://~~/b.git', :tag => '0.0.1'

  target 'A_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

This is A Library's podspec

```html
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'A'
  s.version          = '0.0.2'
  s.summary          = 'summary of A pod'
  s.swift_version = '4.0'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'https://bitbucket.org/000/000'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Hyobin Kim' => 'myemail' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://dolfu@bitbucket.org/~~/A.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
  s.source_files = 'A/Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'B'
end
```

This builds normally in xcode.

However, when you use the 'pod spec lint' command on a terminal, it prints the following message:

```html
ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `B` depended upon by `A`) during validation
```

To solve this problem, I typed 'pod spec lint --sources =' https: // ~~ / b.git '', but the following message is displayed.

```html
Encountered an unknown error (An unexpected version directory `Classes` was encountered for the `/Users/dolfu/.cocoapods/repos/bitbucket-b/B` Pod in the `B` repository.) during validation
```

What is the way to solve this?
I ask for your good answer. (If you have a good example, please write your link)

Comment: What happened to this issue? Did you fix it? How?